# Problem with custom method in CRUDrepository (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a web app for a small driving school using spring boot. At this time, I am trying to create the tables that uses foreign keys: a student will have multiple evaluations, so I am doing a 1:N association. The problem is, when I try to run the project for testing, I obtain this error (only going to put the cause):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property rut found for type ResultadosPsicotecnicos!
```

I did a custom method to fetch all the evaluations of a student, but for some reason it doesn't work. I looked into the database to see if the column was actually created and this is the code I saw:

```
-- Table: public.resultados_psicotecnicos

-- DROP TABLE public.resultados_psicotecnicos;

CREATE TABLE public.resultados_psicotecnicos
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    fecha_evaluacion character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nota1 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nota2 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nota3 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nota4 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    rut bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT resultados_psicotecnicos_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkf57g1daekqxergtw9kck81esq FOREIGN KEY (rut)
        REFERENCES public.students (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.resultados_psicotecnicos
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I am kinda new to this framework, so maybe the error is obvious, but I don't see it. Now I'll show the classes and repositories.

This is the structure of the project:

[image]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

## Hibernate Propierties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

# Hibernate auto ddls
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

Student.java

```
package net.BBB.ProjectB.entity;


import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "nacionalidad")
    private String nacionalidad;

    @NotNull(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "edad")
    private long edad;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "rut")
    private String rut;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "sexo")
    private String sexo;

    @NotNull(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento")
    private Date fecha_nacimiento;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "domicilio")
    private String domicilio;

    @NotBlank(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Este campo es obligatorio")
    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private long telefono;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ResultadosPsicotecnicos> resultadosPsicotecnicos;

   /* constructors, getters and setters ommited */
```

Do not confuse this `rut` in Student with the one in ResultadosPsicotecnicos.

ResultadosPsicotecnicos.java

```
package net.BBB.ProjectB.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Resultados_Psicotecnicos")
public class ResultadosPsicotecnicos {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rut", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Student student;

    private String fecha_evaluacion;

    private String nota1;

    private String nota2;

    private String nota3;

    private String nota4;

    public ResultadosPsicotecnicos() {}

    public ResultadosPsicotecnicos(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    /* getters and setters ommited */
```

ResultadosPsicotecnicosRepository.java

```
package net.BBB.ProjectB.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph.EntityGraphType;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.BBB.ProjectB.entity.ResultadosPsicotecnicos;

@Repository
public interface ResultadosPsicotecnicosRepository extends CrudRepository<ResultadosPsicotecnicos, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Student.resultadosPsicotecnicos", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    List<ResultadosPsicotecnicos> findByRut(long rut);

}
```

Here at the end is the custom method that is causing errors. I am going to use the `id` of the student at the moment, later if I fix this I will use the `rut`, but for now the column of the foreign key is called `rut` and it uses the `id` of student.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the JPA is trying to find column rut in ResultadosPsicotecnicos as you have specified findByRut in ResultadosPsicotecnicosRepository.

1. Modify the findByRut in  ResultadosPsicotecnicosRepository as below because you need to specify the object name of your entity in the jpa repository and not the db column name
   List findByStudent_id(long studentid);
2. Alternatively, you can try the below solution.
   To get the List of ResultadosPsicotecnicos for a particular Student, then you need to add the below method in StudentRepository

@EntityGraph(value = "Student.resultadosPsicotecnicos", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
Student findById(long id);
and on the top of your Student Class, please add the below line
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Student.resultadosPsicotecnicos", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("resultadosPsicotecnicos") })

Comment: forgot to answer: this did the trick to run the service, thank you very much. Have some problems fetching the data from table Resultados_Psicotecnicos, but that is another story.